# External HDD is not working on Mac notebook

Tags: macos, hard-drive, mac, external-hard-drive, external-drive

I have this extenal HDD drive that connects to computer via cable with blue USB port (USB 3.0).

It's working perfectly fine with my new ASUS laptop, but it's not working with an old MacBook (OS X 10.6.8).

I can say that the disk is spinning and vibrating. It has a working LED, but it's not detected by Mac in any way. It is not shown in disk util. Here's the output of diagnostic commands when disk is connected to a Mac: https://gist.github.com/slavafomin/67b6824f8c8a01ec17ff

My ASUS laptop (Windows 8.1) shows it like: "StoreJet Transcend USB Device". I think that I have this model of HDD: http://www.transcend-info.com/Products/No-284 (1 TB version). It is formatted as exFAT.

What can be the reason for this?

I would be glad to provide additional information and update my question on request.

#### UPD 1

I've formatted USB flash drive as exFAT to test if it is supported. It works flawlessly.

Comment: What version of OSX are you? lower than 10.6.5 had dificulties, because exFAT is a propreitary Windows File System.

Comment: MacBook is operated by OS X 10.6.8 (Snow Leopard).

Comment: Update: I've formatted USB flash drive as exFAT to test if it is supported. It works flawlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure exFAT is not supported by any OS older than 10.6.5 - we can't tell from you github which OS you have.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ExFAT
I don't think it's a usb issue.

Comment: Hi Cap! Thanks for your reply. Why the device then is not shown at all? If I understand correctly, if the problem were with filesystem format then device will be detected but it will just fail to mount the filesystem. In my case device is not shown at all in Disk Util. Am I wrong?